# Thinking about how adding extra variables affect linear regressions

Tags: regression

I have two models.  First,
$$z=\alpha_1x+\alpha_2+\epsilon$$
and second,
$$z=\beta_1x+\beta_2y+\beta_3+\epsilon.$$

What factors affect whether $\alpha_1\approx\beta_1$? Note that I don't care how accurately either model predicts $z$. I only care about how similar the coefficient of the $x$ term is in both models.

Assume both $x$ and $y$ actually predict $z$ and don't interact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the omitted variable $y$ is correlated (in the sample) with the other independent variable $x$, the slope coefficient will be biased/inconsistent. The intercept will remain biased/inconsistent unless the mean of $y$ is zero.